# Unit tests for multiple static classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have the below pseudo code to explain the code I've to write some unit tests for.

I wanted to create a unittest for ClassA but because it uses ClassB (that is using ClassC) I'm in doubt how to approach it. I'm not sure if the code itself should be structured otherwise or I just don't know how to handle the Testing this the right way.

I should be able to mock ClassB but then I should create a ClassBFactory? But then I've the idea I'm creating everything by Factories just for being able to write Unit Tests.

```
Public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
    }

    public object DoSomething(object request)
    {
        object result = ClassB.GetMeSomething(request.Property);

        // .. do other things

        return result;
    }
}

public static class ClassB
{
    public static object GetMeSomething(string param1)
    {
        string convertedParam = ClassC.Convert(param1);

        // ... do other things with convertedParam

        return result;
    }
}

public static class ClassC
{
    public static string Convert(string param)
    {
            // .. Some logic to do a external API request
            string result = ExternalAPI.Get(param);

            return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot create factory for static classes. You have to refactor this into normal classes with interfaces. This is what happens when you fill your project with static classes.

Comment: @FCin but when I create normal classes with interfaces. Then I should use the factory method to be able to mock them right?

Comment: Agree with FCin. In order to make the code testable, you should use DI (Dependency Injection). Then you can inject Mocks easily.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you pass interfaces as dependencies (via constructor or public properties) then you can mock them without factories. If your classes implement `IDisposable`, then unfortunately factories will be necessary.

Comment: Unrelated: Having a bunch of static classes _can_ be a code smell anyway. I learned that it's working out well for me that whenever I feel urged to have a static class, I really try hard to find a way to not having to make it static. So if I can ever avoid it, I don't use static classes. That leaves me with classes that are only static if I really have some very good reasons. Also, I try to avoid dependencies between static classes. And that's for the exact problem you are facing now - testability.

Comment: Ok clear, but when I pass interfaces as dependencies the constructor of ClassA would become ClassA(IClassB,IClassC) and in some situations it could become a longer list of interfaces to be passed through the constructor?

Comment: Yes, so? That's what DI Frameworks are for. They'll resolve those dependencies for you. They still can be configured to be singletons, so you'll have the same effect as if they were static - just that they aren't.

Comment: How you structure your code highly depends on framework you are using. If you have many classes chained together you probably want to decouple them with `Dependency Injection`.

Comment: Thanks Fildor & FCin I'm going to refactor the code so I can use DI and write UnitTests

Comment: @FCin so I would create Interfaces that are just for DI, right?

Comment: You would create interfaces to allow for easy switching of implementation. If you have references to interface in many places and want to change implementation, you don't have to modify your existing code (Opened/Closed principle). With `DI` you can register concrete classes and it will work.

Comment: @FCin I already changed my code and it works. But it feels a bit wrong that I get more 1 : 1 relations between class and interface.

Comment: You don't have to create interface for every class. Just for those that you expect to change in the future or they already have multiple implementations.

Comment: @FCin but to use the DI method they also must have interfaces, right? So I mean for the classes that I use for DI there are becoming more 1:1 relations.

Comment: The point is: Interfaces allow you to _mock_ functionality and `DI` allows you to _decouple_ functionality. Your classes don't have to have interfaces if you want to just pass them with `DI`, but if you want to also make them testable, then yes, they have to have interfaces. There are also other ways of testing classes. Look at `Microsoft.Fakes` and `Reflection` as well as passing `Func<>` as parameter. Don't go over the board with interfaces, because then you will end up with a lot of abstractions. Find a nice balance of what needs to be abstracted and what doesn't.